# How do I validate text_field_tag used for searching purpose in rails 4.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In `homepage/index`:

```
<%= form_tag :controller => 'hotels', :method => 'get' do %>
<%= text_field_tag :search, nil, :class => 'search-box'%>           
<%= submit_tag "Search", :name=>'btnsearch' %>
<%end%>
```

In `hotels_controller`:

```
def index
     @hotels= Hotel.where('hotel_location LIKE ?',"%#{params[:search]}%")
```

I am new to Rails and I am wondering that how to `validate` `text_field_tag` for `nil` value.Means if no record was found, then display the error message without redirecting to the **hotel/index** page.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is somewhat paradoxial:

> If no record was found, then display the error message without
>   redirecting to the hotel/index page

What you're asking is to perform the functionality which can *only* be achieved after you've sent a request to your app, and then display the message without redirecting?

---

**Ajax**

You'll probably be best using [Ajax (Asynchronous Javascript and XML)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)):

[image]

This is a way of sending & receiving requests outside the scope of the typical "HTTP" request (IE without reloading the page). This sounds like what you're looking for, as it will ensure you're able to return the data you want *without* redirecting to your `index` view again.

The importance of Ajax is that it provides many HTTP developers with the ability to create much more "organic" interaction structures within their applications (IE not having to reload the page every time you want to do something)

Ajax is very simple to implement - I'd recommend it for you:

--

**Search**

Here's what I'd do:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$(document).on("ajax:success", "#search", function(status, data, xhr){
    $(this).append(data);
});

#config/routes.rb
...
resources :hotels do
    get :search, on: :collection
end

#app/views/homepage/index.html.erb
<%= form_tag hotels_search_path, method: :get, id: "search", remote: true do %>
   <%= text_field_tag :search, nil, :class => 'search-box'%>           
   <%= submit_tag "Search", :name=>'btnsearch' %>
<% end %>
```

This will send a "get" request to your `hotels_search` path - which will allow you to do the following:

```
#app/models/hotel.rb
class Hotel < ActiveRecord::Base
    def self.search search
       results = where('hotel_location LIKE ?',"%#{search}%") if search
       if results
          return results
       else
          return "No Records"
       end
    end
end

#app/controllers/hotels_controller.rb
class HotelsController < ApplicationController
   respond_to :js, :json, :html
   def search
      @hotels = Hotel.search params[:search]
      respond_with @hotels, layout: false
   end
end
```

Comment: You might want to change this: `where('hotel_location LIKE ?',"%#{params[:search]}%")` to this: `where('hotel_location LIKE ?',"%#{search}%")`.

Comment: Thanks - missed that!

Answer (score 0):

> how to validate text_field_tag for nil. if no record was found, then display the error message without redirecting to the hotel/index page.

*Looks like you need to validate it on client side. You can checkout [`bootstrap validator`](http://bootstrapvalidator.com/) which is really nice for using validations on client side.*

If you want to write your own js to handle it then you can do something like this:

```
$(document).on("click","#your_btn_id",function(e){
  var textValue = $(this).closest(".search-box").val();
  if(textValue == ""){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("Please enter some value");
  }
});
```

**Update:**

You can also utilize [`HTML5 validations`](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/html/html5-form-validation/) and won't need any js

```
<%= form_tag :controller => 'hotels', :method => 'get', :validate=>true do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :search, nil, :class => 'search-box', :required => true %>           
  <%= submit_tag "Search", :name=>'btnsearch' %>
<%end%>
```

If you don't want to use ajax then you can do:

```
def index
  @hotels= Hotel.where('hotel_location LIKE ?',"%#{params[:search]}%")
  if @hotels
    #your action
  else
    flash[:notice] = "Please enter a valid value"
    render 'your_form_action'
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks.I have another issue, if i am typing an invalid value then i am redirected to the `hotel/index` page where i got nothing. So, i want to validate if nothing is there then don't redirect me to that page

Comment: @John if you want to validate it for incorrect values then you'll have to change your UI and use ajax or what you can do is inside your index action check for hotel value and if it's nil then redirect user back to your search page and show some flash message like invalid value. Which option suits your needs? Will update my answer accordingly

Comment: @John I have updated my answer for non ajax way. Let me know if it worked for you

Answer (score 0):

Since Rails generates HTML5, I am sure you can leverage its [`required`](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_form_attributes.asp) attribute to have Search text box as a mandatory field on your view page. Like this:

```
<%= form_tag :controller => 'hotels', :method => 'get' do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :search, nil, :class => 'search-box', :required => true %>           
  <%= submit_tag "Search", :name=>'btnsearch' %>
<%end%>
```

Just to be assured that your controller doesn't get nil in `params[:search]`, you can change controller's index action with:

```
before_filter :validate_search, :only => [:index]

def index
  @hotels = Hotel.where('hotel_location LIKE ?',"%#{params[:search]}%")
  if @hotels.present?
    # other operation here!
  else
    redirect_to :back # will work only when referrer is present!
    rescue ActionController::RedirectBackError
      redirect_to root_path
  end
end

def validate_search
  if params[:search].nil?
    redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Enter few characters to search!'
  end
end
```